# Mocikto how to correctly verify mock calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I am new to kotlin unit testing and trying to use Mockito for the same

```
private val mockClient: MongoClient = Mockito.mock(MongoClient::class.java)
private val mockDatabase: MongoDatabase = Mockito.mock(MongoDatabase::class.java)
private val mockCollection: MongoCollection<Document> =
        Mockito.mock(MongoCollection::class.java, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) as MongoCollection<Document>

private val dao = MyDao(mockClient)
```

Testing the get method of dao that fetches data from mongo works fine using **when** and **thenReturn**

```
val query = BasicDBObject("_id", someId)
Mockito.`when`(mockClient.getDatabase(DB_NAME)).thenReturn(mockDatabase)
Mockito.`when`(mockDatabase.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME))
    .thenReturn(mockCollection)
Mockito.`when`(mockCollection.find(query)).thenReturn(iterable)
Mockito.`when`(iterable.iterator()).thenReturn(cursor)
Mockito.`when`(cursor.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false)
Mockito.`when`(cursor.next()).thenReturn(validDocument)
assertEquals(expectedData, dao.get(someId))
```

The problem arises when verifying the mock for calls during insertion

```
Mockito.verify(mockCollection, Mockito.times(1)).insertOne(dataDocument)
dao.create(data)
```

The error is

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mongoCollection.insertOne({//documents goes here})
```

I tried directly using the API and its inserting data in the correctly, the issue lies in the testing not sure if I am correctly using the verify?
Any helps suggestion appreciated.

Comment: How do you create `dataDocument`? Also use `mockito-kotlin` library. It has `whenever` instead of `when` and `Mockito.mock(MongoClient::class.java)` can be replaced with `reified` i.e. `mock<MongoClient>()`

Comment: dataDocument is an actual Mongo Document
val dataDocument = Document()
// Fill in other details

Comment: I haven't worked with mongo for very long time, but my suspicion lies within `Document` class, it not having equals/hashcode methods and thus your test `Document` and actual in service `Document` differ and that's why mockito fails to match as they are not equal even tho they have the same values.

Comment: What does `dao.create(data)` do? is it in the right order? `verify` should be called at the end of your test case. 
If `dao. create(data)` is expected to do the `insert` operation then change the order of method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

`verify()` should be called at the end of your test case (just like assertion statements). Try calling `verify()` after `create()`.

Also, I suggest you use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) for Kotlin. It looks much more idiomatic and user friendly.